# NSData not loaded properly in UIWebView lodadata method

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsurl, loaddata, uiweb

i want that `UIWebView` working offline. When i first visit the url than i have done the below code to save data in document directory in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

```
NSCachedURLResponse* response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]                                     cachedResponseForRequest:[webview request]];
NSData * data = [response data];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@temp”, basePath];
if (response)
{
    BOOL isSaveFile = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:filePath];
}
```

When i open the `webview` second time i will check that file exist or not. I get the file exist i have done the below code to open file from local.

```
NSData * sData = (NSData *)[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (sData.length)
{
[webview loadData: sData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}
```

Above code is not working properly and i am getting the below output.

[image]

Please guide me. what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: are you sure that data is "text/html" ?

Comment: @sage444 NOT fixed but most of time i am getting .pdf file or some times website url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set proper `MIMEType`, because `UIWebView` have no idea how to render the raw data.

```
NSCachedURLResponse* response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:[webview request]];
NSString *MIMEType = response.response.MIMEType;
NSData * data = [response data];
```

then load

```
[webview loadData: sData MIMEType:MIMEType textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Comment: MIMEType was my mistake..  It was @"application/pdf" insted of @"text/html" Thanks